# Camel Validator return entire message

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route,

```
<from uri="a">
<to uri="validator:schema.xsd">
<to uri="b">
```

Say the XML file being validated is missing two elements, the validator seems to stop once it finds the first missing element and returns a message saying it was missing.

Is it possible to carry on validating the XML file to look for any other missing elements and return that in the error message so the sender doesn't have to keep sending to find out which elements are missing or invalid?

Comment: I suggest to google about javax.xml.validation.Validator and see what properties and options it has for turning such functionality on|off. As well run with DEBUG level at org.apache.camel.processor.validation as Camel DEBUG every warn/error/fatal reported by the validator. Though the thrown exception is constructed to return the list of errors/warns. So are you sure you only see 1 and not all errors?

Answer (score 0):

[Validator component](http://camel.apache.org/validation.html) throws [SchemaValidationException](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/validation/SchemaValidationException.html), if validation fails. This exception contains method `getError()` returning `List<org.xml.sax.SAXParseException>`.
You can use this to transform message to `List<org.xml.sax.SAXParseException>` in onException block.

Following code catches SchemaValidationException, transforms body to `SchemaValidationException.getErrors()` and marks exception as `continued`, to continue routing and return this list on output route.

```
from("timer:simple?period=1000")
    .setBody(constant(XML_INVALID))
    .to("direct:a");

from("direct:a")
    .onException(SchemaValidationException.class)
        .to("direct:validationErrors")
        .continued(true)
        .end()
    .to("validator:test.xsd")
    .to("log:result");

from("direct:validationErrors")
    .setBody(simple("${property.CamelExceptionCaught.errors}"))
    .end();
```

---

Note: This example was tested with following resources

XML_INVALID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shiporder orderid="str1234">
  <orderperson>str1234</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>str1234</name>
    <address>str1234</address>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <quantity>745</quantity>
    <price>123.45</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

test.xsd copied from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- definition of simple elements -->
<xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
<xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>

<!-- definition of attributes -->
<xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string"/>

<!-- definition of complex elements -->
<xs:element name="shipto">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="address"/>
            <xs:element ref="city"/>
            <xs:element ref="country"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="title"/>
            <xs:element ref="note" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="quantity"/>
            <xs:element ref="price"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="orderperson"/>
            <xs:element ref="shipto"/>
            <xs:element ref="item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="orderid" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```